# Strange type of file appli

Tags: php, upload, file-type

I created a script to upload files on the server and store the filetype and filename on mysql database.

When i try to upload file via php script it works with image files.
In mysql database some files are not correctly stored and in the filetype, it save a strange filetype

```
appli
```

I tried to search on the web but i cannot find this kind of filetype.

Comment: Can you post your sample code?

Comment: That looks like the start of an `application/...` mimetype, cut short to 5 chars. Is your field limited in length? What type of field is it?

Comment: ah, yes... it was 5 chars limited... now i changed to 255. It's a varchar...
Thanks will check what happends